# Java 'file.delete()' Is not Deleting Specified File

Tags: java, file, delete-file

This is currently what I have to delete the file but it's not working. I thought it may be permission problems or something but it wasn't. The file that I am testing with is empty and exists, so not sure why it doesn't delete it.

```
UserInput.prompt("Enter name of file to delete");
String name = UserInput.readString();
File file = new File("\\Files\\" + name + ".txt");
file.delete();
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

I now have:

```
File file = new File(catName + ".txt");
String path = file.getCanonicalPath();
File filePath = new File(path);
filePath.delete();
```

To try and find the correct path at run time so that if the program is transferred to a different computer it will still find the file.

Comment: have you checked file and folder permissions?

Comment: What environemnt: Unix or Windows?

Comment: Are any exceptions thrown?  What is the return value of the `file.delete()` call?

Comment: What's the `\\Files\\` for? And do you really mean to append `.txt`?

Comment: Also remember to close any possible programs that could have the file open in it. I was trying to delete a db while it was open in a db browser.

Comment: If this is under Windows, it is because the file is open (or mmap'd). Windows locks open files, and then File::delete cannot delete them.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Be sure to find out your current working directory, and write your filepath relative to it.

This code:

```
File here = new File(".");
System.out.println(here.getAbsolutePath());
```

... will print out that directory.

Also, unrelated to your question, try to use `File.separator` to remain OS-independent. Backslashes work only on Windows.

Comment: And contrary to popular opinion, forward slashes *do* work on Windows. Just don't expect Windows to *return* paths with forward slashes.

Answer (score 85):

The problem could also be due to any output streams that you have forgotten to close. In my case I was working with the file before the file being deleted. However at one place in the file operations, I had forgotten to close an output stream that I used to write to the file that was attempted to delete later.

Comment: Same concept, but I found that I had to close *input* streams.

Comment: Its works after FileInputStream/FileOutputStream  closed. thanks a lot.

Comment: This was the last I could think of, but you are right...
Closing the file correctly (not just flush) resolves the issue.

Answer (score 12):

I got the same problem! then realized that my directory was not empty. I found the solution in another thread: [not able to delete the directory through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987921/not-able-to-delete-the-directory-through-java)

```
/**
 * Force deletion of directory
 * @param path
 * @return
 */
static public boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
    if (path.exists()) {
        File[] files = path.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                deleteDirectory(files[i]);
            } else {
                files[i].delete();
            }
        }
    }
    return (path.delete());
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try closing all the `FileOutputStream/FileInputStream` you've opened earlier in other methods ,then try deleting ,worked like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect that the problem is that the path is incorrect.  Try this:

```
UserInput.prompt("Enter name of file to delete");
String name = UserInput.readString();
File file = new File("\\Files\\" + name + ".txt");
if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
} else {
    System.err.println(
        "I cannot find '" + file + "' ('" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "')");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to delete file first close all the connections and streams.
after that delete the file.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was the close() that was not executing due to unhandled exception.

```
void method() throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    parse(fis);
    fis.close();
}
```

Assume exception is being thrown on the parse(), which is not handled in this method and therefore the file is not closed, down the road, the file is being deleted, and that delete statement fails, and do not delete.

So, instead I had the code like this, then it worked...

```
    try {
        parse(fis);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        fis.close();
        throw ex;
    }
```

so basic Java, which sometimes we overlook.

Comment: In this case, I suggest to keep the `fis.close()` inside a `finally` too

Answer (score 2):

As other answers indicate, on Windows you cannot delete a file that is open. However one other thing that can stop a file from being deleted on Windows is if it is is mmap'd to a `MappedByteBuffer` (or `DirectByteBuffer`) -- if so, the file cannot be deleted until the byte buffer is garbage collected. There is some relatively safe code for forcibly closing (cleaning) a `DirectByteBuffer` before it is garbage collected here: https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph/blob/master/src/main/java/nonapi/io/github/classgraph/utils/FileUtils.java#L606  After cleaning the `ByteBuffer`, you can delete the file. However, make sure you never use the `ByteBuffer` again after cleaning it, or the JVM will crash.