# How to modify a txt file with a temporary file in java?

Tags: java, database, grid, store, temporary-files

just wondering why it is not working the code we are using...
i create a program that manages products of a store, in a specific of the program the user can add or delete products that are stored in the warehouse,
the application shows a grid, that represents part of the store, referring with a ProductDatabase that is uploaded when the user add the product or delete it.
for the adding function no problems... when i try to delete a product i read the ProductDatabase, i get the string of which product to delete, i create a temporary file copying in it all the data without the string line referring to the prodcuct i have to delete, then i rewrite the ProductDatabase.
at this point i should have uploaded the Database by deleting the product and the specific file line. i don't know why it works and sometimes it doesn't. well i know it sounds strange but that is what happens!
this is the code:

```
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.Toolkit;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;
 import java.io.*;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Kastriot
 */
public class Preleva_Prodotto extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/** Creates new form Ricerca_Prodotto */
public Preleva_Prodotto() {
    initComponents();

    String fileLine;

    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("DatabaseProdotti.txt");
        BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        int i = 0;
        String[] Prodotto = new String[21];
        String[] DetProd = new String[6];

        while ((fileLine = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {

            Prodotto[i] = fileLine;
            DetProd = Prodotto[i].split(",");
            NomeProdotto = DetProd[0];
            Descrizione = DetProd[1];
            Peso = Integer.parseInt(DetProd[2]);
            CodiceID = DetProd[3];
            Posizione = DetProd[4];
            DataReg = DetProd[5];



            if (Peso <= 500) {
                if (Posizione.equals("C0")) {
                    jLabel1.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel3.setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (Posizione.equals("C1")) {
                    jLabel13.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel4.setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (Posizione.equals("C2")) {
                    jLabel14.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel5.setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (Posizione.equals("C3")) {
                    jLabel15.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel2.setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (Posizione.equals("C4")) {
                    jLabel16.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel6.setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (Posizione.equals("C5")) {
                    jLabel17.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel7.setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (Posizione.equals("C6")) {
                    jLabel18.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel8.setBackground(Color.red);
                }


            } else if (Peso <= 1000) {
                if (Posizione.equals("B0")) {
                    jLabel19.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel16.setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (Posizione.equals("B1")) {
                    jLabel20.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel17.setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (Posizione.equals("B2")) {
                    jLabel21.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel18.setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (Posizione.equals("B3")) {
                    jLabel22.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel19.setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (Posizione.equals("B4")) {
                    jLabel23.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel20.setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (Posizione.equals("B5")) {
                    jLabel24.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel21.setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (Posizione.equals("B6")) {
                    jLabel25.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel22.setBackground(Color.red);
                }


            } else if (Peso > 1000) {
                if (Posizione.equals("A0")) {
                    jLabel26.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel9.setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (Posizione.equals("A1")) {
                    jLabel27.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel10.setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (Posizione.equals("A2")) {
                    jLabel28.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel11.setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (Posizione.equals("A3")) {
                    jLabel29.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel12.setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (Posizione.equals("A4")) {
                    jLabel30.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel13.setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (Posizione.equals("A5")) {
                    jLabel31.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel14.setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (Posizione.equals("A6")) {
                    jLabel32.setText("<html>" + NomeProdotto);
                    jPanel15.setBackground(Color.red);
                }


            }

        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PianoB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    String lineToRemove = jTextField1.getText();

    if ((!lineToRemove.equals("A0")) && (!lineToRemove.equals("A1")) && (!lineToRemove.equals("A2")) && (!lineToRemove.equals("A3")) && (!lineToRemove.equals("A4")) && (!lineToRemove.equals("A5")) && (!lineToRemove.equals("A6"))
            && (!lineToRemove.equals("B0")) && (!lineToRemove.equals("B1")) && (!lineToRemove.equals("B2")) && (!lineToRemove.equals("B3")) && (!lineToRemove.equals("B4")) && (!lineToRemove.equals("B5")) && (!lineToRemove.equals("B6"))
            && (!lineToRemove.equals("C0")) && (!lineToRemove.equals("C1")) && (!lineToRemove.equals("C2")) && (!lineToRemove.equals("C3")) && (!lineToRemove.equals("C4")) && (!lineToRemove.equals("C5")) && (!lineToRemove.equals("C6"))) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "La posizione inserita non è esistente, inserire una posizione libera tra quelle disponibili!", "Operazione non riuscita!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        PosizioneVuota = false;
    }

    try {

        File inputFile = new File("DatabaseProdotti.txt");
        File tempFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Kastriot\\Documents\\Università\\tmpFileProdotti.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

        String[] DetProd = new String[100];
        String fileLine;
        while ((fileLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
            DetProd = fileLine.split(",");
            PosDaPrelevare = DetProd[4];

            if (!PosDaPrelevare.equals(lineToRemove)) {
                writer.write(fileLine);
                writer.newLine();
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Il prodotto presente nella posizione " + (lineToRemove) + " è stato prelevato con successo!", "Operazione riuscita", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                PosizioneVuota = false;
                NuovaSchermata = true;


            }
        }
        reader.close();
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        inputFile.delete();

        tempFile.renameTo(new File("C:\\Users\\Kastriot\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\EasyStorage1.0\\DatabaseProdotti.txt"));


        if (PosizioneVuota) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "La posizione " + (lineToRemove) + " non contiene alcun prodotto", "Operazione non riuscita", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        if (NuovaSchermata) {
            Situazione_Generale_ SitGenFrame = new Situazione_Generale_();              //Apre la schermata Situazione Generale
            //Centrare la finestra e mostrala sullo schermo
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            SitGenFrame.setSize(950, 480);
            Dimension frameSize = SitGenFrame.getSize();
            SitGenFrame.setLocation((screenSize.width - frameSize.width) / 2,
                    ((screenSize.height - frameSize.height) / 2));

            SitGenFrame.setVisible(true);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Preleva_Prodotto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell what the error is?

Comment: there isn't! =( sometimes the product is deleted and sometimes nothing happens!

Comment: ok thank you for the comment about the code... it is the first program we are making. hope that at your first time you were much better...

Comment: comment the `inputFile.delete()` and see if `tmpFileProdotti.txt` exists?

Comment: I wonder why sometime you use relative path and sometime absolute path. Hint: even on Windows, you can use forward slashes, to avoid these ugly double backslashes... You should check the result of delete(), it might fail. In this case, the renaming can fail too.

Comment: the inputFile.delete deletes the file databaseProdotti.txt that i created,

Comment: Honestly, I don't remind my first code, it is long ago. My remarks doesn't aim to be vexing, more to give suggestions where improvements can be done. :-) Actually, I first thought it was enterprise code, but when I saw 'university' in the path, I understood you were beginner. So, sorry if my tone was vexing. I see lot of similar code from beginners in the Processing forum...

Comment: Your intermittent issue might be a timing problem on Windows: if the closing of the file isn't finished, the deletion can fail. Honestly, I don't know if it can happen, but it is a possibility.

Comment: ok i followed your advices and i changed the format of the code, checking the temporary file i noticed that it works. the problem in effect it is when it tries to rename the file, it doesn't work. i don't know why... thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to change the file path to absolute path in `inputfile`.

```
File inputFile = new File("DatabaseProdotti.txt");
```

Change it to -

```
File inputFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Kastriot\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\EasyStorage1.0\\DatabaseProdotti.txt");
```

You can find more about this issue at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4485744/813471).